# $\ln x \approx \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $0.5<x<1.5$. Why?

Tags: logarithms, approximation

I've been looking at series expansions of data after different transformations and accidentally found that

$\ln x \approx \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}}$ when $0.5<x<1.5$

This is a particularly helpful approximation for me, but I don't want to use it without having some sort of derivation. Is there any trick I'm missing?

Comment: They agree to order $x^2$ around $1$.

Comment: Notice that the values, first derivatives, and second derivatives of $\ln x$ and $(x - 1)/\sqrt{x}$ all agree at $1$. So the Taylor series centered at $x = 1$ all agree up to second order, and the third- and higher-order terms aren't very big. The goodness of the approximation drops off very rapidly once you get too far below $0.5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Taylor expansion on both sides around $x=1$. Let $t=x-1$, then you get

$$\ln(1+t)\approx t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}-\cdots,$$

and the right-hand side becomes

$$\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t}}=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{3t^3}{8}-\cdots.$$

So the first two Taylor terms of the functions agree. The leading order difference is $\,t^3/24$, which remains small if $|t|<0.5$, i.e., $0.5<x<1.5$.

Comment: It also makes the third order term in the difference 8 times smaller than it would be with just taking the second order Taylor polynomial.

Comment: Yes. There are many ways to approximate a function. I'm not sure how good a Pade approximant is for $\ln x$ around $x=1$. But I can tell this formula is very good for financial applications to calculate compound interest. If the interest rate is not too high, it works.